# Footer fade in and fade out

Tags: footer

i want to made a footer like on this website **(www.8layertech.com)**, im a newbie.

The footer is fading out when you scroll and when you stop scrolling on any place the footer will fade in. I know that it can be made in jquery but i dont know where to start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413439/fade-in-out-fixed-position-div-when-user-scrolls-to-very-bottom-of-page

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` does not have a built in way to catch `scrollstart` or `scrollstop` events.
James Padolsey has created a plugin that implements events for this:
[Link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/)
You can use that and implement what you need. 8layertech seems to be using the same code.